# Display data from another table rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a fundings table and organisations table.Funding table has organisation_id. In the funding form I have a field name_of_organisation which is a dropdown field which displays all organisations in organisations table. When I select an organisation from dropdown and after submit. I am not able to display the organisation details in funding show page. Kindly help

funding.rb

```
class Funding < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :organisation
end
```

organisation.rb

```
class Organisation < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :fundings
end
```

show.html.erb (funding)

```
<% @organisations.funding.each do |funding| %>
  <p><strong>Name of the Organisation:</strong><%= organisation.name_of_organisation %></p><br>
<% end %>
```

error

```
undefined method `funding' for nil:NilClass
```

Funding_controller

```
def show
 @funding = Funding.find(params[:id])
end
```

error continues

undefined method `funding' for nil:NilClass

```
<% @organisations.funding.each do |funding| %>
  <p><strong>Name of the Organisation:</strong><%= @funding.organisation.name_of_organisation %></p><br>

<% end %>
```

[image]

Comment: What's in your fundings_controller show action?

Comment: @BenTrewern check the update

Comment: So the only instance variable you have is `@funding`.  `@funding.organisation` is what your are looking for.

Comment: @BenTrewern okay. Any idea how it will work?

Comment: Well `<%= @funding.organisation.name_of_organisation %>` used in your view will show your organisation name.  I'll leave the rest to you. :-)

Comment: @BenTrewern I tried what you recommended. But I still get the error undefined method `funding' for nil:NilClass. Please check the update above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are looking for this? 
Funding_controller

```
def show
 @funding = Funding.find(params[:id])
end
```

show.html.erb (funding)

```
  <%unless @funding.organisation.blank?%>
    <p><strong>Name of the Organisation:</strong>
    <%= @funding&.organisation&.name_of_organisation %></p><br>
  <%end%>
```

Comment: on doing what u suggested. On the funding show page. Name of organisation repeats number of timings the same organisation is used.

Comment: please check the image above

Comment: @NAVROOPSINGHSIDHU I couldn't get your question, if you want show only funding's organisation name than you don't need to go through loop. let me know what do you want to show at funding show page?

Comment: I just want the name of organisation for which funding is applied. Just one organisation name

Comment: @NAVROOPSINGHSIDHU Then its more simple than before. i just did your code according to your association, please check the updated answer, it's what exactly you want.

Comment: @NAVROOPSINGHSIDHU Hmm glad to know that, just a side note brother, you really need to work hard on basic of ruby and rails :) anyway feel free to ask any further help.

Comment: @Gabber I am just new to rails. Just few weeks i started learning.

Comment: @NAVROOPSINGHSIDHU Alright! make sure you are learning by the help of SO. :)